# Find elements with given class and multiple attribute Jquery

Tags: jquery, each

How do we do a each() with multiple attributes?

```
Working:
$(".divReplies[userId="+userIdTemp+"] ").each(function(index, element) {

});
```

Not working:

```
$(".divReplies[userId="+userIdTemp+" replyId="+replyId+"]").each(function(index, element) {

});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have use [separate brackets](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/) for each attribute:

```
$(".divReplies[userId="+userIdTemp+"][replyId="+replyId+"]").each
```